# React Native Navigation go to top of stack on Bottom Tab click

Tags: react-native-navigation

This should be easy to implement, but I tried many things and still no go.

I have a simple Bottom Tab Navigator (Stack) with who nested Screens. I have a component with a button to lead to the second screen with shared element transition. When on the second screen, I would like the tab button at the bottom to take me directly to the bottom of the stack.

What I have so far:

```
<BottomTab.Navigator>
   <BottomTab.Screen
        ...
        listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
          tabPress: (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            //=> navigation.navigate('Search', { screen: 'Search' }); This works but the shared element transition gets jumpy
            //=> navigation.popToTop(); This works but the next time you click it, it fails because there is no screen in the stack to pop up to.
          },
        })}
      />
```

It's a little disappointing that the bottom tab button doesn't have the options to pop to the top stack screen if stacked. Then we start with ugly preventDefault hacks.

As you can see in the code above, I explain what doesn't work. One would think I could just get the current stacked screen we are on, and if it's the bottom one, avoid `popToTop()`, but alas, there is no decent way to get it. [I tried this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/), but I'm getting errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a method `navigation.canGoBack()` that allows you to check if there's a screen 'below'. Maybe you can use it to check if you need to call `navigation.popToTop()` or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unmountOnBlur. It doesn't work in my case because I'm not navigating between tabs by actually pressing the tab icon but this could be what you're looking for.

```
 <BottomTab.Navigator>
   <BottomTab.Screen
        ...
        options={{ unmountOnBlur: true }}
      />
```